# Computational complexity and recursion - Is this analysis correct?

Tags: algorithm, recursion, time-complexity, complexity-theory, master-theorem

[image]

Hi! I have a doubt about this resolution of this algorithm analysis, specifically referred to the *return min(L[i:j+1])*: why is it considered O(n)?: it always refers to a defined slice, with a limited possible dimension (j<=i+2)

Comment: `min(L[i:j+1])` is O(1) in that code, because the size of the sub-slice is at most 3. Another way to say that is that this is a base case for n<=3 (taking n to be j-i+1).

Comment: Your doubts are correct - because that base case is O(1) and not O(n), the recurrence is wrong: it should be T(n) = 3T(n/3) + c. The correct recurrence gives the solution T(n) = Theta(n), whereas the recurrence in the picture is Theta(nlogn) as you've written.

Answer (score 2):

For simplicity, consider size of the list to be a power of 3.

---

### Algorithm

```
if j-i+1 <= 3:
    # Compute their minimum
    return min(i:j+1)
```

The `if` statement forms the base case. Time complexity of above statements is `O(1)`. However, *the if statement will be executed `n/3` times.*

---

### Recursion Tree

```
                                     T(n)
                                       |
                 ______________________|______________________
                |                      |                      |
                |                      |                      |
             T(n/3)                 T(n/3)                 T(n/3)
                |                      |                      |
         _______|_______        _______|_______        _______|_______
        |       |       |      |       |       |      |       |       |
        |       |       |      |       |       |      |       |       |
     T(n/9)  T(n/9)  T(n/9) T(n/9)  T(n/9)  T(n/9) T(n/9)  T(n/9)  T(n/9)

        .       .       .      .       .       .      .       .       .
        .       .       .      .       .       .      .       .       .
        .       .       .      .       .       .      .       .       . 
        .       .       .      .       .       .      .       .       .    
      T(1)    T(1)    T(1)   T(1)    T(1)    T(1)   T(1)    T(1)    T(1)    --- (n/3) * T(1)
```

It should be obvious from the recursion tree, that for an array of size `n`, `if` statement will be executed `n/3` times. Hence, overall complexity of `if` statement is `O(n)`.

---

The reason `if` is executed `n/3` times and not `n` is that *recursion ends when we encountered an sub-array of size 3*. If the the recursion came to an end when we encountered an sub-array of size 1, then it would have been executed for n times.

Comment: Your answer is right, but I think a bit confusing because you've concluded that the complexity is O(3^n) (because the size of the input is assumed to be 3^n). I think it's clearer if you say "for simplicity, assume n is a power of 3", and then you'll conclude that the complexity is O(n).

Comment: I think your calculations are off too: if the input is size 3^n, then the body of the if statement will be executed (3^n)/3 times, not n/3 times.